# How to convert date string in EDT to UTC date?

Tags: java

I am reading data from upstream system and it returns the date in string format like this,

```
String dateFromUpstream = 11-14-2022 10:41:12 EDT
```

Now, I want to convert this string to a date format of UTC timezone and then store it into my entity.

I tried the following way,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
LocalDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateFromUpstream, formatter).toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

But this doesn't change the date to UTC timezone. It still gives me the same date with UTC instead of EDT at the end of the string.

Anyone know how I can do this and then store into an entity?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to convert to.  Convert to an `Instant`.

Comment: Can I not use the localdatetime? I want to store this value into an entity and then I am using this value to compare with another datetime value from an entity which has the date time in UTC format.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` represents a civil time _without a time zone_, like "January 3, 5:25 pm."  It could mean many different actual instants in physical time.  A `LocalDateTime` isn't a thing that even has a timezone like UTC.

Comment: @Lewis12 A `LocalDateTime` is inherently ambiguous, and cannot represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` is nothing but a date and a time-of-day. So a `LocalDateTime` of January 23, 2023 at 12:00 PM does not tell us if you meant noon at Tokyo, Toulouse, or Toledo — which would all be different moments several hours apart on the timeline. Novices at date-time handling often use `LocalDateTime` when they really should be using one of the classes that represent a moment: `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, & `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: By the way, (a) `EDT` is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). And (b) learn to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been covered *many* times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the given date-time string into a `ZonedDateTime` with the corresponding `DateTimeFormatter` and then convert the resulting `ZonedDateTime` into an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) or another `ZonedDateTime` corresponding to UTC, using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateFromUpstream = "11-14-2022 10:41:12 EDT";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateFromUpstream, dtf);
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Or get a ZonedDateTime at UTC
        ZonedDateTime zdtUTC = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(zdtUTC);

        // If you want LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdtUTC.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/YIFsWY).

**Output**:

```
2022-11-14T15:41:12Z
2022-11-14T15:41:12Z
2022-11-14T15:41:12
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

**Note**: As suggested by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque), you can convert the parsed date-time into an `OffsetDateTime` at UTC as shown below:

```
OffsetDateTime odtUTC = zdt.toOffsetDateTime()
                           .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Good Answer. I would change `ZonedDateTime zdtUTC` to be `OffsetDateTime odtUTC` since you are adjusting to an offset rather than a time zone. Same result in the end, but the intent would be more clear.

Comment: I am not able to access `withZoneSameInstant`. I only see these two, `with(TemporalAdjuster adjuster)` and `with(TemporalField field, long newValue)`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Lewis12 Check if you have imported `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. This method has been available since Java 8. Also, make sure you are calling this method on an instance of `ZonedDateTime`. It seems you are trying to call it on an object of `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: yes I have imported that.

Comment: @Lewis12 You can see that code, cut-and-paste unchanged, [run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/YIFsWY).

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for the valuable suggestion and for editing the answer. I just wanted to avoid a call to `toOffsetDateTime` before applying `OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`.

Comment: nvm, I was accessing that property after converting it to an Instant instead of accessing it directly from ZoneDateTime. This works. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Okay, *now* I see the somewhat clumsy extra steps you were trying to avoid. Still I think using `OffsetDateTime` is best to make clear the intentional use of offset versus zone.